# How to perform Segue on Appdelegate when a Push Notification Arrives on Device and Pass Payload Values to Destination ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

Right now I am Able to receive the Payload from the Parse Service as you can see below:

```
{
    "where": {
        "objectId": "00000011",
        "deviceType": "ios"
    },
    "data": {
        "alert": "You have a new Message",
        "sound": "alert_chat.mp3",
        "viewController": "chat_controller",
        "nick_from": "username1",
        "nick_to": "username2"
    }
}
```

using the following line of code i can know the viewController that i want to segue on Appdelegate on didReceiveRemoteNotification:

```
if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"viewController"]  isEqual: @"chat_controller"]){

        NSLog(@"ViewController:%@", [userInfo objectForKey:@"viewController"]);
    }
```

Now i want to segue to the Chat Controller but also pass the values ( nick_from, nick_to ) To that specific viewController Because this ViewController expects this 2 values in order to call the conversation between this 2 users.

**EDIT**

The solution I've found for this problem is the following.

```
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        [(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController setSelectedIndex:2];

        UINavigationController *nav = [[(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:2];

        UIViewController *detail = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"conversation_detail"];

        nav.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.098 green:0.737 blue:0.611 alpha:1];
        nav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [nav.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
        nav.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
        [nav pushViewController:detail animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcast a NSNotification via `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` in the AppDelegate, let the first view controller listen to that notification and if it is time to segue to the detail controller set the objects in `prepareForSegue:`

Comment: I'm new to all this. Can you give a example so I can have a clear view of it. thanks.

Comment: as this is pretty standard and basic there are enough examples to search for.

Comment: I'm using Parse.com Push Notification, another Question the NSotification center can be called from any ViewController?

Comment: what sense would a notification center make if you could listen on it just in one place?

Comment: please finally check the documentation. it is all written down.

Comment: How I do to show the ViewController that will Observe the Data?